# How do I avoid unwrapping an Option returned from accessing a HashMap with an Option as the value?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I am following [the introductory book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html). In [section 13.1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#storing-closures-using-generic-parameters-and-the-fn-traits), the authors implemented a "Cacher" and asked the reader to implement it with a `HashMap`. I have gotten it to work, but I'm not quite content because of a call to `unwrap()` which seems a bit out of place.

Specifically, in the `Cacher::value()`, the `Some(v) => v.unwrap()` call is what displeases me - considering the documentation of `unwrap()` states that calls to the function should be avoided. What is a better/more idiomatic suggestion for doing what I'm trying to accomplish?

The code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Cacher<T> {
    calculation: T,
    hmap: HashMap<u32, Option<u32>>,
}

impl<T> Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            hmap: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        match self.hmap.get(&arg) {
            Some(v) => v.unwrap(),
            None => {
                let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
                self.hmap.insert(arg, Some(v));
                v
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cache = Cacher::new(|x| x * x);
    let v = vec![cache.value(1), cache.value(2), cache.value(3)];
    println!("v: {:?}", v);
}
```

Comment: Why have an `Option` in `HashMap<u32, Option<u32>>`?

Comment: I think the idea was that you could either have a value computed or not, so I thought it would be well represented by an Option. But now that you say it, it's clear that there is no need because the HashMap itself does this by either having the entry or not.

Comment: If you were to keep the values as `Option<u32>`, you can treat no entry and a `None` entry as the same by only matching on `Some(Some(v))`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=06ebe5782bd6d2eaa2555435176f9151)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to have an `Option` in the `HashMap<u32, Option<u32>>` because the `HashMap` itself may represent whether a value is cached or not. The new and improved code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Cacher<T> {
    calculation: T,
    hmap: HashMap<u32, u32>,
}

impl<T> Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            hmap: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        match self.hmap.get(&arg) {
            Some(v) => *v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
                self.hmap.insert(arg, v);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cache = Cacher::new(|x| x * x);
    let v = vec![cache.value(1), cache.value(2), cache.value(3)];
    println!("v: {:?}", v);
}
```

Comment: Next on your journey, you might look into the `entry` API for `HashMap`. As written, when the value is not found you compute it and then insert it, which requires duplicating the work of hashing the key and figuring out where it goes. With the entry API, you get the slot once up front and then decide what to do based on if it's inhabited.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I’ll make sure to look into it when I decide to delve into the more advanced stuff!